# How to extend Visual Studio 2012 suggestions with IntelliSence

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I don't know how to extend VS 2012 to provide this functionality or any 3rd Party tools that provides this but I'd like the ability to have in the intellisense the ability to provide coding suggestions if certain classes perform a certain way. Example, if I write the code:

```
UsersContext db = new UsersContext(
```

I'd like the intellisense to include suggestions (or an option to provide them):

```
UserContext.UserContext()
-------------------------------------------
SUGGESTION: Wrap new reference in Using(){ } statement. 
WHY: This class extends IDisposable. This will handles MemoryDisposal of object.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ReSharper will do *something* like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resharper and Coderush do this to some extent through their code analysis features.

[ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)

[CodeRush](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/CodeRush/)

They both offer free trials and you can see if they fit your need.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to go for Vissual Assist X.It has alot of features and has the ability to do as you requested.